# Follow hyperlink and scroll to make hyperlink appear at top of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the following hyperlink:

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(ROW($F$8); COLUMN($F$8));LEFT($F$8;2))
```

The hyperlink is written in a cell with word wrap.

I want Excel to scroll after a user has clicked the hyperlink to make the hyperlink appear on the top visible row. I was hoping Excel had functionality for this, but the best I could find was a suggested VBA solution in another stackoverflow question:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

However, that event is not triggered by my hyperlinks, so it has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Range("e11").Address Then
Range("e11").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Assuming hyperlink is in the cell E11.